# what is the max count of appsettings.json files in vs2022(.net core 6)

Tags: .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

Our project has multiple deployments (Dev, QA, Prod...) , can any one tell what is maximum config files (appsettings.json) count that supports in vs2022?

Comment: I don't think there is a hard limit, or if there is, its something _very_ large.

Comment: How many environments do you expect to have?

Comment: our project has different requirement as of now we deployed qa in 5 and prod in 3 sets will come more in future